# How do I change the CTA URL after password reset in Django?

Tags: django

So I've set Django's built-in password reset feature(?) in my project. Everything works fine, except redirection in `/password_reset_complete` page. The custom login url in my project is `/login`, but the CTA button in `/password_reset_complete` page is linked to `/accounts/login` , which causes error apparently. 
How do I change the CTA link in `password_reset_complete` page? Thanks

Comment: What's your LOGIN_URL setting? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#login-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `LOGIN_URL` in your settings.py so:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login' #login here is the name of the url not the url itself
```